# Запоминание ролей

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, авторизация

Никак не могу разобраться как сделать разделение ролей у пользователей, мне это чисто для курсача надо, помогите люди добрые пж, уже все что можно перерыл, там либо полностью переделывать в сто раз больше, либо вообще ничего непонятно.

Файл авторизации:

```
  session_start();

  $name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']),
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $pass = md5($pass."abc7709");

  $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

  $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '$name' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
  $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

  $role = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status` =  '1'");
  $user1 = $role->fetch_assoc();

  //echo $user1;

  if ($user1 == '1'){
    $_SESSION['role'] = 'admin';
  }
  else {
    $_SESSION['role'] = 'guest';
  }


  if (count($user) == 0) {
    echo "Такой пользователь не найден";
    exit();
  }

  setcookie('user', $user['name'], time() + 3600 * 24, "/");

  $mysql->close();

  header('Location: index__main.php');


?>
```

Файл где проверяю работает ли роль:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin'){ 
    echo '<a href="../admin"><button class="green">Панель администратора</button></a>';
  }
  else {
    echo 'То что может видеть не зарегестрированый пользователь';
  }
?>
```

Что лично я заметил так это то что из базы данных $role или $user1 не берет вообще никакой информации, потом что при проверке путем if(empty($_SESSION['role']));
то все выводит, до этого пробовал и через просто $user, и попробовать переделать это под var, но все равно ничего не выходит, голова уже соображает, путаться начинаю

Answer (score 0):

[fetch-assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) возвращает массив, т.е целиком строку из базы. Поэтому условие `if ($user1 == '1')` не будет работать.

Далее,

```
`SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status` =  '1'`
```

выберет **ВСЕ** строки, где status=1, невзирая на логин-пароль.
Итого, делаем единственный запрос:

```
 $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '$name' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
 $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
 if ($user['status'] == '1'){
....
```